# How can I convert binary to heximal while keeping the zeros in the beginning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Here is an example:

```py
>>> x = int(input("Enter some numbers with 1's and 0's: "))
Enter some numbers with 1's and 0's: 001 10100 00010 1100100 1000
>>> y = # some code here
>>> print(y)
001 14 0002 64 8
```

What would I assign for y?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]

Comment: What did you try? Please show your attempt(s).

Comment: What is the rule for printing leading zeros? It looks completely arbitrary.

Comment: @DYZ I have not tried anything, I am kind of new to python

Comment: `print(*(f"{x.partition('1')[0]}{int(x, 2)}" for x in some_numbers.split()))` where `some_numbers = '001 10100 00010 1100100 1000'`

Comment: SO is not a do-my-homework site. You should come here with a specific question, and you are expected to know at least some Python.

Comment: So I wrote an answer cause I wanted to figure out how to write it elegantly, but this question doesn't show any effort so I downvoted. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework".

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to get the leading zeroes, then convert the rest to an int but format it as hex.

```
import re

def formatter(s):
    """Convert binary string s to hex, but keep leading zeroes."""
    zeroes = re.match(r'0*', s)[0]
    binary = s[len(zeroes):]
    i = int(binary, 2)
    return '{}{:x}'.format(zeroes, i)

x = '001 10100 00010 1100100 1000'
y = ' '.join(map(formatter, x.split()))
print(y)
```